# How to find which machines are configured for specific DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

We are currently removing ancient DC's from our domain so we can upgrade and I ran into an issue the last time one was removed. We had a few old UNIX machines that were pointing to a certain DNS server (which we were removing). This caused a few login issues (that were promptly resolved) however we don't want to run into this issue again.

Is there a way to tell (without logging into every server) what machines may be configured to point to a specific DNS server so I can update it before removing it?

Comment: Configure a debug log in the ancient DC and log the ip-adresses of the clients using it? For example in [Windows Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759581(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you're talking about non-Windows machines, you can't even rely on something like SCCM or PowerShell remoting, which leaves debug logging on the DNS servers that are getting decommissioned as your most viable option.

[Fortunately, it's pretty easy to setup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759581%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

All you'd need to do after setting it up and waiting a little bit is parse the log for IPs making requests, switch those computers to a new DNS server, and repeat until you don't see any more requests and are satisfied that all your machines have had enough time to make a DNS request that would have been captured.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the link - Will definitely go this route.

Answer (score 3):

It's not very easy unless you have a solid inventory management system already in place throughout your domain, such as System Center Configuration Manager, that is capable of collecting data from every machine in your environment.

Even with SCCM, or the ability to run `Get-DnsClientServerAddress` or `ipconfig /all` on every machine in your environment remotely from a central server, you'll still have to parse the output, because you likely do not have the exact same number of network interfaces in every machine, or each "front side" and "backup" network interface won't be named the same, etc.  I've done this with SCCM, where I collect this data from every machine, including what IP addresses they have configured for their DNS servers, and I shove all that data into a SQL database so that I can query it and make SSRS reports out of it, but it's not 100% reliable, for the reasons I mentioned before.

Then of course there's logging in to every DNS server you have and turning on debug logging so you can log all the queries.

Comment: Yup - we had to do this at $job[-1]. There, we ended up deploying  a perl-wrapped tcpdump script to the DNS servers which just collected client IPs and connection count. Worked great. I suspect one could do the same with Windows debug logging.

Comment: Thanks for the info about SCCM. We're not using it however it's good to know it can be done. Going to go the logging route because of the non-Windows machines.